# object(specifically armature) ignors axis(in this case x axis) during a location animation

Tags: animation, rigging, axis

I was trying to animate an armature character move from one place to another:
This might look confusing but all you need to know is that the armature needs to move from location a to b
[image: This might look confusing but all you need to know is that the armature needs to move from location a to b]
[image]

But when I insert a keyframe for the original location, pass the time line forward, insert the end keyframe after moving the armature to the correct location, and then play the animation the armature moves to the incorrect location:
[image]
It appears that the animation ignors x axis
I tried it with z too
I repeated the same keyframe process and moved the armature slightly down at the end keyframe.
And sure enough it went back to image three when played
except this time it was moved down slightly.
so for some reason the x axis is ignored during the animtion
I dont remember pressing anything incorrectly but i must have
or this is a glitch
pls help and thank you!

Comment: You can mute individual f-curves in the editor, make sure the x-axis loc is not muted.

Comment: How exactly do I check this? Thanks.

Comment: I FIXED IT THANK YOU SO MUCH